# Redirecting and rewriting a dynamic URL to static SEO friendly URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am having some trouble rewriting and redirecting my URLs. This is what I am trying to do:

Currently I have this URL: `domain.com/server.php?id=$1`

I have that URL above which rewrites to: `domain.com/details/$1`

The problem I am having is when you go to: `domain.com/server.php?id=$1` it doesn't redirect to my SEO friendly URL.

Does anyone know why?

This is my current rewrite for the url:
`RewriteRule ^details/(.*)/ server?id=$1 [L]`

Comment: Check `virtualhost.conf` and `httpd.conf`, look for `AllowOverride None`. If you see that, change it to `AllowOverride All`.

Comment: Rewrite != Redirect

Comment: I know rewrite is not the same as redirect. I am having trouble getting the correct redirect code.

Comment: @mopsyd I just checked the `virtualhost.conf` and `httpd.conf`,  it says `AllowOverride All`

Comment: Anyone else have any ideas on how to fix this issue I am having?

Comment: Have you verified that your rewrite rules are working at all? Try redirecting all requests to one file and see if that carries over. If not, your apache configuration is off.

Comment: `RewriteRule . index.php [L]` Should do that. If that does not work, check your apache settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my what I found to work for me:
`# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+server\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ details/%1? [R=301,L,NE]`

`# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^details/([^/.]+)/?$ server.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^details/([^/]*)$ /server.php?id=$1 [L]
```

It will give you the URL: `domain.com/details/$1`. Just make sure you clear your cache before testing it.

Comment: I just tried the code above and it did not work. I could't even use my url domain.com/details/$1. I already have the rewrite figured out which is this code:                                                                                                 `Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^details/(.*)/ server?id=$1 [L]` I am having trouble redirecting the old URL to the new one I just did the rewrite on.

Comment: rewriting is usually only done in one direction, from SEO-friendly to the "standard way". Thestandard will always work!
For redirects just use the SEO-friendly links